# Flyway With Oracle

Tags: oracle, compatibility, flyway

I am using Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 version and I have used flyway core jar of version 6.4.2. Are they both compatible? 
Error: Flyway Enterprise Edition or Oracle Upgrade Required: Oracle 12.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Enterprise Edition.

I am not using Flyway Command Line.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. Support for Oracle 12.1 was removed from the community edition in [Flyway 5.2.0](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes#5.2.0).

Possible solutions would be to

1. Upgrade the database to 12.2 or later
2. Downgrade to an earlier version of Flyway
3. Buy the Flyway enterprise version

Answer (score 2):

This restriction is no longer in place from Flyway version 10 (October 2023). We have updated Flyway so that it works with ALL supported database versions, so if you upgrade to version 10 you can access all supported versions of Oracle.

The community version of Flyway now works with All versions of Oracle.