# Why even older version of flyway dont let using them with Oracle XE 11g?

Tags: java, flyway

Is there any old version of flyway that supports Oracle XE 11g. I just got down to 5.7.1 version and still the same error :
 `Flyway Enterprise Edition or Oracle upgrade required: Oracle 11.2 is past regular support by Oracle and no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition and Flyway Pro Edition, but still supported by Flyway Enterprise Edition.`

I have tried downgrading flyway version from 8 to 5 and still the same error. Is there any chances to resolve or only one thing that can help is to update oracle XE?
I have found [Flyway With Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951224/flyway-with-oracle)  and tried downgrading but same error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Oracle 11g was dropped in [Flyway 5.0.0](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes.html#5.0.0)

> - Oracle 12.1 is now the new minimum supported by Flyway Community
>   Edition

The latest community version to support Oracle 11g is Flyway 4.2.0.