# Which flyway-core and flyway-commandline Version can i USe for Oracle 19c 19.0.0.0.0

Tags: oracle, flyway

I want to use Flyway Community for my Database migrations.

The Flyway features and Editions Website ( https://www.red-gate.com/products/flyway/editions ) says that it only supports the current version.

I was looking everywhere for Release-Notes or a Compatibility List that can show me the newest Flyway Community Version i can use for my Oracle 19c 19.0.0.0 Database.

Could you help me please? I also asked Copilot but it also did not return a Version i can use.

I am using Maven to get the flyway core library and the flyway-commandline tools. Currently i am using flyway 5.1.4 which is not good securitywise.

I checked the Following Websites:

https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/supported-databases/oracle-database

[Flyway With Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951224/flyway-with-oracle)

https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/database-version-support-143754067.html

https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/release-notes-and-older-versions/release-notes-for-flyway-engine

I also assked Copilot.
Which Flyway Community version supports Oracle 19,1? Sadly the answer did not help.

Kind Regards and Thank you,

Burak